# Why the same width&height images don't have the same sizes?

Tags: java, c, image, image-processing

Why the same width&height images don't have the same sizes? As I understand they both have the same amount of pixels, don't they? So why can one weigh more than the other?

Comment: In what format are the images stored? Most image formats make use of compression techniques.

Comment: because they might differ in their definition , that pixel per inch is not the same , high definition images have more pixels per inch , thus heavy size despite of same width and height

Comment: You mean size on the screen ? Proportion ? Size on disk ?

Comment: Images can also be saved with different compressions, so depending on the complexity of the images, they could produce files of different sizes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Bitmap format (files with extension .bmp):

1. The header size could be different. (In header, the file format, image size, image color type, and such kind of additional information is stored.)
2. The size for one pixel could be different. 1 bit/pixel for black/white images. 8 bit/pixel for at-most-256-color images. 24 bit/pixel for standard images. 32 bit/pixel for images with transparency information (Although .bmp files nearly-never have transparency information, .png files often have.).

In the JPEG, PNG, or other format: 1, 2 from the above are also applied. Additionaly,

1. The image is compressed and stored (for example, jpg, png, ...).
2. They may have layer or animation information (for example, gif).

Answer (score 1):

Because `pixels` can have different size

It can be 1bit(black&white),8bit,16bit,24bit,32bit and even [more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)

---

So,two images with same width(480px) and height(640px) but with with different pixel size have different size.

i.e 480 X 640 X 32bit pixel != 480 X 640 X 1bit pixel